# LUKS2 on-disk format specifications

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, luks

The LUKS1 format has been available for a long time, and the format [specifications](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/LUKS_docs/on-disk-format.pdf) are easy to find. Recently, LUKS2 has been released, which features a number of important changes, such as AEAD and Argon2. The [release notes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/v2.0/v2.0.0-ReleaseNotes) mention that the new on-disk format uses JSON for metadata. I would like to study the on-disk format but would rather not have to dig through the source code to discover the specifications anymore than I have to. Are there any resources which provide the on-disk format?

Comment: They now have [proper specs](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/master/docs/on-disk-format-luks2.pdf), in case you missed it.

Comment: @Arminius Thanks. It seems they went ahead with using JSON for serialization... That's so nasty. Of all the serialization formats, why use an ASCII one for a block device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** A full specification PDF for version 1.0.0 of the LUKS2 on-disk format can now be found in [`docs/on-disk-format-luks2.pdf`](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/a1b606803f6d50e0476867fe9d284399504559a3/docs/on-disk-format-luks2.pdf). (It's a permalink, so check the master for updated versions.)

---

It's in [`docs/LUKS2-format.txt`](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/master/docs/LUKS2-format.txt).

They have a comment saying:

```
Note: these are temporary documentation notes only.
The more formal definition will be published later.
```

So a full comprehensive documentation beyond this file doesn't seem to be currently available.